# How can I chain my method calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, method-chaining

I have an object:

```
var mubsisapi = {
        step1   : function(){alert("a")}, 
        step2   : function(){alert("b")}
    }

$.extend(false, mubsisapi)
mubsisapi.step1().step2();
```

It is give `step1()` but not give `step2()`. `step2()` does not give an alert. How can I do this?

Comment: Edited to remove references to JSON … which you aren't using.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not JSON, but javascript object. It's not [fluent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), but it can be:

```
var mubsisapi = {
        step1   : function(){alert("a"); return this;}, 
        step2   : function(){alert("b"); return this;}
    }

$.extend(false, mubsisapi)
mubsisapi.step1().step2();
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to return `this` from the function if you want to chain it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your object should look like this:

```
var mubsisapi = {
    step1   : function(){alert("a"); return this; }, 
    step2   : function(){alert("b"); return this; }
}
```

returning itself to allow chaining.

Answer (score 2):

```
var mubsisapi = {
        step1   : function(){alert("a"); return mubsisapi;}, 
        step2   : function(){alert("b"); return mubsisapi;}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot chain your function calls. You either have to call them separately:

```
mubsisapi.step1();
mubsisapi.step2();
```

or you can change your step1 function so you can chain them:

```
var mubsisapi = {
        step1   : function(){alert("a"); return mubsisapi;}, 
        step2   : function(){alert("b")}
    }

$.extend(false, mubsisapi)
mubsisapi.step1().step2();
```