# AngularJS controller return value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

The 'controller as' technique for AngularJS was described by [John Papa](http://www.johnpapa.net/do-you-like-your-angular-controllers-with-or-without-sugar/) as:

```
myApp.controller("MainCtrl", [
    function () {
        var vm = this;  // convention - ViewModel
        vm.person = { name: "Bob" };
        return vm;
    }]);
```

What is the purpose of the `return vm;` line? The code works without it.

Comment: From my POV vm is returned to produce a [chained method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7570635/1959948)

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with chained methods (but I've been wrong before) and I don't see how it changes the default behaviour (which is to return `this`).

Comment: To quote the author of the article: "That’s just my convention"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When Angular is creating your controller, it will use the `new` keyword on the function you passed in. Thus, it will construct a new object using the constructor you passed in. Returning objects from your constructor function will cause the Angular to use that instance of your newly created object as with any other use of a JavaScript constructor.

There are some details about the constructing process (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1978474/576725) SO answer) to keep in mind:

1. When the returned object is the same as `this` it can be omitted, as `this` will be used by default.
2. If returning some primitive type [or `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978049/what-values-can-a-constructor-return-to-avoid-returning-this/1978474#comment94888846_1978474) (essentially anything that's `null` or not an `Object`, as described in [the SO answer linked to earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978049/what-values-can-a-constructor-return-to-avoid-returning-this/1978474#1978474)), `this` will be utilized as well.
3. If returning an instance, the reference to this instance will be returned.

---

Saying `this` will be used in 1 & 2 is a trivial oversimplification. Again, see [this answer regarding construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978049/what-values-can-a-constructor-return-to-avoid-returning-this/1978474#1978474) for specific details.

Comment: I agree, but I don't see an explicit answer to the actual question.

Comment: the answer is the content I have written in point 1. As vm is the same as this, it can be omitted because it will be returned anyways...