# Javascript chaining and passing arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

I have read a lots about chained functions in JavaScript, somehow I am really confused if it is possible to pass an argument across the chain.

My main goal is to recreate a "jQuery like" behavior passing the first argument of a function when on chain.

Here is a rough example:

```
;(function(window) {
    var test = {};
    test.a = function(i){
        return i+1;
    };
    window.test = test

})(typeof window != 'undefined' ? window : undefined);

console.log( test.a(1)) //-> should output 2
console.log( test.a(1).a()) // -> should output 3
console.log( test.a(1).a().a()) // -> should output 4
```

PS I guess this could be resolve using prototypes as it is described [here](http://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html) but I really don't want to mess up with prototypes nor to mention that using stored properties for the test object does not fill my needs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570635/how-can-i-chain-my-method-calls

Comment: I don't see how this is possible test.a(1) returns a number and then you want to call a function on this number?

Comment: @Benjamin  I am not using jQuery, furthermore notice the difference that my function a() has arguments passed in.

Comment: @maraca jQuery and D3 act with the exact same behaviour.
I guess I somehow need to bind the test object as an abstract constructor
eg: jQuery(".class").find("a").remove() 
As you see the results from the find method are passed to the remove method

Comment: @Theodore ok, I get it - added an answer.

Comment: @Theodore it is not exactly the same behaviour, jQuery returns objects I think, if a() would return an object which has function a() then you can chain it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this is pretty easy - you need to use a fluid interface and define `valueOf` to allow your object to be represented as a number. You can't get the number but you can get something that represents the number for all practical purposes:

```
var test = {
    counter: 1,
    a: function(n){ this.counter += n; return this; }, 
    valueOf: function(){ return this.counter; }
};

console.log(Number(test)); // when I look at test as a number, it returns the counter
console.log(test.a(1).a(2) + 1); // logs 5
console.log(test + test); // 8
console.log(test.a(1).a(1).a(1) + 1); // 7
```

Personally, I'd prefer returning a new object to make it immutable:

```
function Chain(i){
    this.counter = i;
}
Chain.prototype.add = function(n){
    return new Chain(n + this.counter);
};
Chain.prototype.valueOf = function(){ return this.counter; };
```

Comment: Can you really call your second example 'immutable'? There is nothing preventing you writing`var c = new Chain(3); c.counter = 4;`

Comment: @AndrewShepherd immutable w.r.t `add`, there is almost always a way to mutate state in JavaScript - even if that way goes through overriding `Function.prototype.apply` :)

Comment: Quite interesting approach, however I want to achieve a more independent result on each call of test, using static properties on my method will be messy as I want isolated results on each cycle.
`console.log( test.a(1).a(1) ) // 3`
`console.log( test.a(1).a(1) ) // 5 but it should print out 3 as well`

Comment: @Theodore why don't you pass in an array with the values instead of 1 value and then chaining? This would make it really easy to fullfill those requirements in your comment above.

Comment: @Theodore this is why I added the `Chain` approach below, to address that.